# how to change the size property of a form text input?

Tags: forms, text, input, zend-framework2

1) I didn't find anything in CSS files in relation with the width of form input.
2) I tried this :

```
    array(
        'spec' => array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Your name',
                'size'  => '14',      <---this doesn't work!
            ),
            'type'  => 'Text',
        ),
    ),
```

without any result!

So, is it possible to change the width (size property) of a form text input in ZF2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put size in attributes instead of options

```
array(
    'spec' => array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Your name',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'size' => 14,
        ),
        'type'  => 'Text',
    ),
),
```

Comment: In addition to that, the array key `attributes` can be seen as an equivalent mapping to HTML Attributes!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help but this way doesn't work for me.

Here is exactly my code :

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'attributes' =>array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'size'  => '7',     <--- this doesn't work
            'maxlength'=> '7',  <--- this works
            'value'    => 'Doe' <--- this works
    ),
    'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Your name',
    ),
));
```

However, "size", "maxlength" and "value" are equivalent : both are HTML attributes!

**So I found in public/css/bootstrap.min.css** :

```
input, textarea, .uneditable-input
{
    width: 206px;   <---change this value and it's ok
}
```

!!! Pay attention to refresh your browser !!!

Comment: Well, that is quite obvious, if you change the size via CSS, the change of the HTML Attribute size doesn't have any effect..., maxlength only defines the maximum character count so....

Comment: try to add also an attribute **class** named **span6** (bootstrap2)